# Material UI Components not Rendering when built with express app (Production)

Tags: reactjs, express, material-ui, amazon-lightsail

I'm building a frontend with React and Material UI, and everything is running smoothly when I run npm start.

I also have an express app that serves a production build of this frontend (I run npm run-script build and take the prod build and place it in my express app's target destination). When I run this express app locally (with node app.js), everything is rendering and operating smoothly there as well.

Now, when I go onto my Amazon Lightsail linux instance that I was using to deploy, and run the express app over there with node app.js, the app runs, but all of the material-ui components do not render at all. All I see is the background.

Initial investigation led me to believe that within ReactDOM.render, the UI I was rendering needed to be wrapped in MuiThemeProvider. Have tried this to no avail. Its led me to a couple questions.

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzgll.png)

In my production build (build->static->css) all I have is one css file, which only lists the background. This makes sense as to why I can at least see the background when I deploy. My question here is, I'm using makeStyles and withStyles in my jsx a lot to create the bulk of my classes. In my production build, should these get compiled down into css?

My other question is if it should get compiled down to css, why am I able to see all of my material ui components when I run the express app locally on port 9000, but can only see the background when I serve it onto my static port on lightsail? It's the same build, so I almost find it hard to believe there's something wrong with my build.

Anyone experience anything like this? Any tips or advice on how to debug would be appreciated, I've been stuck for quite some time.

Comment: You should probably also first confirm if the React + MUI app runs properly after making the production build.
`serve -s build`

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar Thanks for the tip. Just confirmed that when using serve -s build, all of my components are rendering. Tried doing the same on the linux lightsail server, but serve is not a command on that server apparently.

Comment: Any specific reason you are making React + MUI app (SPA) separately when eventually you are using it in an Express app?

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar Good question, and maybe you could provide me some advice. I will admit that I'm a novice at best. I went with React+MUI as my frontend/SPA because I wanted exposure to the two technologies. It was my impression that it was "best practice" to deploy this in production with a technology that allows server-side code. Namely, I wanted to use potentially a few apis, for sending email msgs and such, that to my understanding cannot be done from the front-end. I wanted to try to serve this express app on a lightsail server to get an understanding of how people serve these apps

Comment: @HarshayBuradkar Previously, the only app I ever deployed to the web was with Heroku. Not only is Lightsail significantly cheaper, but I felt using Heroku was not giving me the whole picture of how deployments to the web work. There felt like there was a lot of abstraction on Heroku

Comment: The question is actually too broad for the platform.  

You might want to check/research if you want an SPA or not.  
Otherwise you can do all of it in the Express App alone.  

If you want an SPA, you probably should deploy it separately on a server, and use Express app as a pure API and deploy that separately as well. No need to build and copy it into the Express app.